# How to check for duplicates with an added condition

Tags: duplicates, powerbi, dax, street-address

I'm working with a table of addresses in Power BI. The table also has a column marking some condition, it could be anything so I'll just label it "condition".

I'm trying to create a column (or measure) showing duplicate addresses. The problem I'm having is that both/all duplicates need to meet that other condition. Rows that don't should just be ignored from the start. I thought these nested IF statements would work:

```
Duplicate = 
IF(
    CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table),
    FILTER(Table,Table[Condition]="Yes")),
    IF(
        CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table),
        FILTER(Table,Table[Address]=EARLIER(Table[Address])))>1,
            "Duplicate",BLANK()
    )
)
```

But duplicate pairs where only one row meets the condition are still marked. What am I doing wrong?

I need all rows elsewhere so I can't filter the query. Also, I know I could add the condition to the concatenation, but that seems sloppy and I assume there's a more "correct" way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how your outer `IF` function is supposed to work since the first argument is an integer rather than True/False.

Try this instead:

```
Duplicate =
IF (
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            Table,
            Table[Condition] = "Yes" &&
            Table[Address] = EARLIER ( Table[Address] )
        )
    ) > 1,
    "Duplicate",
    BLANK ()
)
```

---

**Edit**: As you pointed out, this didn't work exactly as intended. Try one of the following instead:

```
Duplicate =
IF (
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            Table,
            EARLIER ( Table[Condition] ) = "Yes" &&
            Table[Condition] = "Yes" &&
            Table[Address] = EARLIER ( Table[Address] )
        )
    ) > 1,
    "Duplicate",
    BLANK ()
)
```

or

```
Duplicate =
IF (    
    Table[Condition] = "Yes" &&
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            Table,
            Table[Condition] = "Yes" &&
            Table[Address] = EARLIER ( Table[Address] )
        )
    ) > 1,
    "Duplicate",
    BLANK ()
)
```

Comment: This does work, but it also marks rows that don't meet the condition IF there are at least two rows that do. I have the same address five times, two meet the condition, three do not, and your code gives me "Duplicate" five times. Is that the expected result?

Comment: It's not what I intended but I see why it's doing that. I'll post an edit shortly.

Comment: The two columns in your new edit do only mark rows meeting the condition, but unfortunately they don't factor the condition into counting duplicate rows in the first place. So in a two-row address match where only one meets the condition, I'm getting one row marked duplicate.

Comment: Ah, so you need the condition inside and outside then. I'll update.