# Power BI Dax Find Earliest match and preform operation

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm working in Power BI, and I need to do this in DAX to keep it from having to re-read the 200K PDF files(8hr refresh time).
I have a table that has duplicated ID and Step values with a different time stamp. I need to find the earliest ID and subtract all matching ID's from the earliest Time stamp. I can then use the newly found delta time value to filter the table.

I'm struggling because I need to compare on ID out of the table to all of the the other ID's looking for matches.

Example Data:

[image: Example Data]

Final Data:

[image: Final data]

This post got me close, but in the IF statments they equal it to "Yes" and not to the ID in the row. [How to check for duplicates with an added condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60383538/how-to-check-for-duplicates-with-an-added-condition)